# javascript toggle script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this js code, which display and hide some content on a page after click on a button. I've added second script (slickbox2), which do the same with another content by clicking on 2nd button. The problem I need to resolve is when 1st content is displayed and I click on 2nd button, I want to hide the 1st content. Thank you!

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    //hides the slickbox as soon as the DOM is ready
    jQuery('#slickbox').hide();

    // toggles the slickbox on clicking the noted link  
    jQuery('#slick-toggle').click(function() {
        jQuery('#slickbox').toggle(400);
        return false;
    });

    jQuery('#slickbox2').hide();
    // toggles the slickbox on clicking the noted link  
    jQuery('#slick-toggle2').click(function() {
       jQuery('#slickbox2').toggle(400);
       return false;
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed a few points.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[id*=slickbox]').hide(); //hide your slickboxs

    $('#slick-toggle').click(function(){
        $('#slickbox').show();
        $('#slickbox2').hide();
    });

    $('#slick-toggle2').click(function(){
        $('#slickbox').hide();
        $('#slickbox2').show();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

BTW You can use $ in place of jQuery in all of your code:

```
jQuery('#slick-toggle2').click(function() {
    jQuery('#slickbox2').toggle(400);
    $('#slickbox1').toggle(400);
    return false;
});
```

Comment: This is what it appears that he is asking, but seems too simple.

Comment: Soooo simple. I'm ashamed. I'm not very familiar with js, so I was afraid that it will take me an hour instead of thinking about it myself. Sorry for such a stupid question. Thank you, Jason and others!

Comment: Using toggle will make your first content appear when you click on the second button if it was hidden

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to give class to all slickboxes e.g. slickbox then your Javascript would be like

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        $('.slickbox').hide();      //hides all elements with class slickbox

        $('.slickbox').click(function(){
             $('.slickbox').hide();
             $(this).toggle(400);
        })
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use hide() function to always hide the first content when clicking on the second button

```
jQuery('#slick-toggle2').click(function() {
  jQuery('#slickbox').hide(400);
  jQuery('#slickbox2').toggle(400);
  return false;
});
```

Don't use toggle or the content will appear if it was hidden